# contentEditable areas::force paragraphs for new lines - cross browsers

Tags: newline, contenteditable, paragraph, execcommand

Firefox breaks new lines with `<br>`, Chrome and Safari are breaking with `<div>...</div>` and Internet Explorer and Opera are using paragraphs `<p>...</p>` for new lines.

I am looking for a method to force each browser to create only paragraphs, when breaking to a new line.

I know [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) supports this function, but how can i realize it simply in my custom editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the execCommand "insertparagraph", e.g. :

```
document.execCommand('insertParagraph',false,'id for new p')
```

Alternatively you could handle the keydown event, catch keycode 13 (without modifiers) and then do whatever you like.

**Corrected**

Comment: Update: as of now, keycode has been deprecated. Use `.key == "Enter"` to do what @MorganTiley mentions about catching keycode 13 in a modern way (I would suggest editing this answer.)

Answer (score 4):

For me was solution to add `document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');` into a `keypress` event in the contenteditable div. For example:

```
element.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == '13')
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
}, false);
```

Hope it'll help someone. :)

Comment: So for every key press ... you re-format the block? would it not be better to check for the enter key code here?

Comment: The problem with this approach is it breaks down if you're inserting bullets. Having started a new list, pressing enter to go to the next bullet inserts a parargraph inside the LI.

Comment: This solution creates `<p>` tag inside already existing tags, which normally works fine, but like @Utkanos said it messes up `<ul>` tags.

Comment: Incidentally... does `ev.keyCode == 13` rather than `ev.keyCode == '13'`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a new `<p>` after breaking to a new line, but you want to keep the formatting of the previous line in place (ie you're breaking from a `<h1>`), combine the answers of @MorganTiley and @PageOnline:

```
editor.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == '13') {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.execCommand('insertParagraph', false);
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    }
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the following as soon as you can in your JS before the user can start editing:

```js
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');
```

Answer (score -4):

You're not specific in which editor you want this function, but you mention CKEditor so I assume you are asking about it. Just add this to your config.js file:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

Comment: no, i need the js code to use it in my own contentEditable DIV and not in ckeditor. i only named ckeditor to give a working example but i am only looking for the js code. thanks